# Intercept Login in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am building a Symfony app, that uses AWS Cognito as the login provider.

Found a great guide at [mybuilder.com](https://tech.mybuilder.com/managing-authentication-in-your-symfony-project-with-aws-cognito/)
It works as expected.

The issue I have, is I want to show a page before the user is fully logged in.

For example, forcing the user to change the AWS assigned password, or block login until they agree to the latest terms and conditions.

I would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

you can create event listener for that, or create your own authentication provider, or add logic to existing authentication provider.

Pay attention in docs to:

`$user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());`

With this line on code you can inject your user in system.

Also you can read about JSON Web Token authentication the same principles you can read there:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-authentication-provider

Second link:

[JSON Web Token symfonycasts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-rest4/json-web-token)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I already have the cognito users logging into my system, using the above guide.

Comment: The issue I have, is forcing the user to change the AWS assigned password, or block login until they agree to the latest terms and conditions.

Comment: Yes, you just need to add logic in authprovider, if user doesnt agreed on terms, just dont call loadByUserName, instead redirect to page with terms

Comment: If you would like to check currently logged in user, you need to get user token in EventListener and check there

Answer (score 1):

First you have to grab the status from the AWS response.  (It might be better to use the attributes. `$result['Users'][0]['Attributes']`)

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    // ...
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
       // ...

        if ($result['Users'][0]['UserStatus'] === 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD') {
            $user->setForcePasswordChange(true);
        }

        return $user;
    }
   // ...
}
```

Then I had to create a controller listener.

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Controller\Layout\EsiController;
use App\Controller\Account\UserController;
use App\Security\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class ForcedPasswordSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $token;
    private $controller;


    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $token, UserController $controller)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        /*
         * $controller passed can be either a class or a Closure.
         * This is not usual in Symfony but it may happen.
         * If it is a class, it comes in array format
         */
        if (!is_array($controller) || !$this->token->getToken()
            || $controller[0] instanceof EsiController
            || $controller[0] instanceof UserController
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->token->getToken()->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User){
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->hasForcePasswordChange()) {
            return;
        }

        $controller = $this->controller;

        $event->setController(function () use ($controller) {
            return $controller->password();
        });
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        ];
    }
}
```

This code just outputs the message `Force password change`, however it is a good starting place.

If you want to force a user to agree to updated terms and conditions, then it is similar, but you just need work it out in the `Subscriber`, and not worry about the `loadUserByUsername` method.